# How to get the hierarchy structure of an element using XML::LibXML in perl

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

Like in this HTML snippet:
`<div class="c1"><span class="c2"><b class="c3"/></span></div>`
The expected hierarchy structure of `b` element should be: `div.c1 span.c2 b.c3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the `parentNode` method in [XML::LibXML::Node](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0128/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod), which simply returns the parent node.  So you can locate your node of interest (`b`) 
and then 'drill' upwards to the top of the tree, collecting suitable information about nodes.  For the desired element.class format:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = q(<div class="c1"><span class="c2"><b class="c3"/></span></div>);

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $xml);

my @hier;

my ($node) = $doc->findnodes('//b');  # only first such node assigned

unshift @hier, join '.', $node->nodeName, $node->getAttribute('class');

while (my $parent = $node->parentNode) {
    last if $parent->nodeType == XML_DOCUMENT_NODE;  # top, <?xml ...    

    unshift @hier, join '.', $parent->nodeName, $parent->getAttribute('class');
    $node = $parent;
}

say for @hier;
```

The `getAttribute` method is in the [XML::LibXML::Element](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0128/lib/XML/LibXML/Element.pod) class.